# Fitting a Weibull function in R

Tags: r, weibull-distribution

I am trying to model some data that follows a sigmoid curve relationship. In my field of work (psychophysics), a Weibull function is usually used to model such relationships, rather than probit.

I am trying to create a model using R. My model will have a 'shape' and 'scale' value. In order to generate this model, I would have thought that R would need to have input vectors from both my X and Y axes (I am plotting size of a visual stimulus against the probability of it being seen). However, the [R help page](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/Weibull.html) gives details of functions that only require either a vector of quantiles (size of stimulus) or a vector of probabilities (presumably, this means my 'probability of seeing' data).

I don't see how R could possibly fit a model on the grounds of only having *half* of my data (i.e. using my X axis (quantile) data, but none of my Y axis (probability of seeing) data).

Am I missing something? I'm not a statistician so I fear there's something fundamental that I've overlooked. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The confusion here isn't really w/ R, it's w/ the nature of the activity you're trying to do. What you want is to use the cumulative Weibull as a [link function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model#Link_function) to *connect* the size of your visual stimulus to the probability of it being seen. To understand more about link functions, it may help you to read my answer here: [difference-between-logit-and-probit-models](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20523//30909#30909).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are trying to do (if I understand you correctly), is to model the probability of the stimulus being seen by a Weibull distribution... *but with the Weibull parameters depending on a covariate, i.e., the size of the stimulus*. So you are really doing a so-called "Weibull regression". The `weibreg()` function in the `eha` package [looks like it should do what you want](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/eha/html/weibreg.html).