# Fitting Weibull distribution in R

Tags: r, probability, distributions, weibull-distribution

My sample data:

```
dat <- structure(list(cum.per.plant = c(0.051, 0.263, 0.66, 0.807, 0.91, 
0.981, 1, 0.012, 0.07, 0.256, 0.47, 0.731, 0.9, 0.989, 1, 0.022, 
0.203, 0.472, 0.777, 0.95, 0.991, 1, 0.005, 0.03, 0.222, 0.46, 
0.773, 0.97, 0.989, 1, 0.06, 0.28, 0.77, 0.92, 1, 0.03, 0.14, 
0.46, 0.85, 0.99, 1, 0.06, 0.27, 0.63, 0.95, 1, 0.04, 0.14, 0.36, 
0.78, 0.98, 1, 0.05, 0.17, 0.35, 0.67, 0.86, 0.98, 1, 0.07, 0.28, 
0.62, 0.9, 1, 0.05, 0.22, 0.51, 0.81, 0.99, 1, 0.09, 0.2, 0.46, 
0.83, 1, 0.08, 0.26, 0.66, 0.93, 0.99, 1, 0.02, 0.12, 0.31, 0.61, 
0.95, 1, 0.05, 0.21, 0.49, 0.81, 0.92, 0.98, 1, 0.01, 0.1, 0.31, 
0.68, 0.93, 1, 0.02, 0.14, 0.52, 0.8, 0.93, 1, 0.01, 0.15, 0.41, 
0.74, 0.91, 1, 0.11, 0.31, 0.7, 0.85, 0.95, 1, 0.02, 0.1, 0.56, 
0.88, 0.99, 1, 0.06, 0.19, 0.59, 0.91, 1, 0.01, 0.12, 0.39, 0.7, 
0.96, 1, 0.09, 0.28, 0.67, 0.89, 1, 0.12, 0.3, 0.67, 0.88, 1, 
0.01, 0.2, 0.62, 0.88, 0.98, 1, 0.04, 0.23, 0.56, 0.83, 0.99, 
1, 0.01, 0.16, 0.55, 0.83, 1, 0.02, 0.22, 0.63, 0.91, 1, 0.017, 
0.143, 0.38, 0.837, 0.956, 1, 0.02, 0.086, 0.204, 0.672, 0.933, 
1, 0.008, 0.091, 0.506, 0.86, 0.972, 1, 0.018, 0.174, 0.503, 
0.778, 0.974, 1, 0.01, 0.19, 0.57, 0.78, 0.88, 0.95, 1, 0.06, 
0.28, 0.65, 0.88, 1, 0.03, 0.17, 0.53, 0.82, 1, 0.01, 0.09, 0.34, 
0.71, 0.9, 1, 0.1, 0.43, 0.79, 0.98, 1, 0.03, 0.22, 0.63, 0.87, 
1, 0.07, 0.29, 0.69, 0.92, 1, 0.03, 0.26, 0.62, 0.89, 1, 0.09, 
0.2, 0.37, 0.71, 1, 0.07, 0.2, 0.59, 0.84, 0.96, 1, 0.06, 0.18, 
0.63, 0.86, 0.94, 1, 0.08, 0.27, 0.61, 0.88, 1, 0.02, 0.18, 0.39, 
0.64, 0.94, 1, 0.07, 0.23, 0.47, 0.78, 1, 0.03, 0.2, 0.46, 0.79, 
1, 0.07, 0.17, 0.31, 0.59, 0.71, 0.93, 1), loc.id = c(7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L), year.id = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), time.id = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)), .Names = c("cum.per.plant", 
"loc.id", "year.id", "time.id"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-279L))
```

The data have four columns:

`cum.per.plant`: cumulative area that is planted by a crop (hence goes from 0 till 1

`loc.id`: locations where data were collected

`year.id`: years when the data was collected

`time.id`: id of the weeks when data were collected.

Hence for loc.id 7 and year.id 4, planting begins from week 2 and reaches 100% in week 8.

I want to implement the below paragraph from this paper if you want to read: 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/v36i8npfwbutiro/Yang%20et%20al.%202017.pdf?dl=0

> Preliminary analysis of the planting data indicates that once planting
>   is initiated, the cumulative proportion of fields planted for a crop
>   in a year at the county level follows a sigmoid pattern, but this can
>   be modified from planting delays due to soil being too wet, we thus
>   fitted  the observed data to the following modified Weibull
>   distribution function
>
> ```
> ProportionFields = 1 - exp(-(DOY - DOYplanting.initiation -
> Days.no.plant/a)^b)
> ```
>
> where ProportionFields is the cumulative proportion of fields that
>   have  been planted in a county, DOY is a calendar day of year, (DOY >=
>   DOYplanting.initiation), DOYplanting.initiation is a  calendar day of
>   year of the earliest planting, Days.no.plant  is the total number of
>   days when planting does not occur due to soil being  too wet since the
>   start of planting. a is a scale parameter and b is a  shape parameter.
>   DOY - DOYplanting.initiation - Days.no.plant represents  the total
>   number of days when planting does not occurr since start of  planting.

I want to use the above approach, so I planned to do this:

1) Fit a distribution to the data. In the above example, they fitted Weibull distribution so I also fitted the same

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fw <- fitdist(dat$cum.per.plant, "weibull")
summary(fw) # shape: 1.2254029, scale: 0.6022573
```

My first question is: 
1) Will the scale parameters and shape parameter be affected by the time step i.e. if the data were collected at daily-level, will my shape and scale parameter get divided by a certain factor?

Now after I get the parameters, I want to implement this equation to calculate the proportion planted each day for a given year and given location.

```
prop.planted <-  1 - exp(- (x/scale parameter)^shape parameter)
```

where x = Day of year - Day of year when planting started - No. of days with no planting since the start of planting

I have the data to calculate $x$ i.e.

Is the equation and my understanding correct of the above paper?

**EDIT:**

Suppose the data follows a beta distribution (and not a Weibull distribution). How can I implement the factor where I calculate x in the beta distribution.

Comment: Please type the part from the paper and do not post a screenshot/image.

Comment: I suggested an edit to the question in an attempt to make it more readable. Feel free to roll back the changes if you don't approve. There is a part of your question missing where you were about to show how to calculate $x$ and it is not clear to me from the description of the data how you would calculate that. For the moment, it seems to me that beta regression is more appropriate for your data.

Comment: successive cumulated values are generally highly dependent. An independence assumption for those would not be tenable; this certainly impacts suitable choice of analysis.

Comment: Maybe relevant:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49500/fitting-a-weibull-function-in-r and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225457/fit-glm-for-weibull-family

Comment: In another question of yours (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/347583/fitting-weibull-distribution-to-percentage-vs-proportion-data) and through a chat (https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77879/discussion-between-jimb-and-crop89) I've tried to convince you that you don't have random samples from a Weibull distribution and that fitting using maximum likelihood in inappropriate.  What you do have is a regression where the form of the curve is (or might be) in the shape of a Weibull.  That's a very different situation.  But no response from you.  How am I mistaken?

Comment: I just responded to your question. For some reason, I did not find the notification of your responses on the chats. Apologies. You are correct. I have a regression and I want to fit a curve that is the shape of Weibull. If I understand it correctly, the below answer fits the regression with the cdf of a weibull?

Comment: No, the answer below still assumes a random sample from a Weibull.  (It uses `fitdist`.)  And I note that the dataset given in this question has the important variable `time.id` which I don't think was given in the other question.

Comment: Okay. hmm. this question I replaced week no. with time id to make it simple. I guess the issue is that my knowledge of probability is really bad and I need to sit down and read more. Thank you for your responses. If you have some time to spare and post some imp pointers in the other link, I will be happy to accept the that as an answer.

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348396/how-to-fit-a-weibull-regression Hopefully now my question is clear. thank you for the discussion with you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*Here's the fitted pdf and cdf (Weibull) for each of locations 1 to 3:*

[image: fitted cdf and pdf, weibull]

Let's break down what we need to do here, keeping in mind that the end goal is to estimate the cumulative proportion of area planted with a certain crop at some value for the random variable time $X$:

1. The first step is to fit a distribution (e.g. $Weibull\left(a:= \text{shape},b := \text{scale}\right)$ or $Beta\left(\alpha,\beta\right)$).

   - You made an error in fitting the data on a Weibull distribution because the function *fitdist* (which uses MLE by default) expects a vector of observations, which would be 'time $X_i$ when some area $i$ was planted with a certain crop'.

     *Here is some R that turns the cumulative data into a vector of observations, which can then be used to fit the distribution with fitdist:*

     ```
     dat <- dat[order(dat$loc.id,dat$year.id),]
     dat$loc.id <- factor(dat$loc.id)
     dat$year.id <- factor(dat$year.id)

     library(plyr)
     #hacking the original data from the cumulative
     to.density <- function(cdf) {  #given input (a cdf vector), returns respective densities
       y <- c(); cdf <- cdf[,'cum.per.plant']
       for (cum in seq(1,NROW(cdf))) {y <- c(y, ifelse(cum==1, cdf[cum], cdf[cum]-cdf[cum-1]))}
       return(y)
     }

     #apply to each location X year in dat, then kbind density data to dat
     densities <- dlply(dat, .(loc.id, year.id), to.density) 
     dat <- cbind(dat,dens=unlist(densities)) 

     #forming a dataset of the variable planting time
     #--because the proportions go to the thousandths place, a pseudo-sample of time.id's with
     #--n=1000 should allow usage of fitdist
     rep.vec <- function(df) {
       y <- c()
       for (row in rownames(df)) {y <- c(y, rep(df[row,'time.id'], df[row,'dens']*1000))}
       return(y)
     }

     #apply to each location in dat - may want to include year.id in the split (excluded)
     time.sample <- dlply(dat, .(loc.id), rep.vec)
     ```
   - Be sure to assess the 'fit' of your estimated parameters (perhaps by calculating the mean square error) on the data.
   - Your code does not indicate that each location and year will be fitted with its own distribution, although you suggest you want to calculate the cumulative area planted for a given location or year.

     *Here is some R for fitting each location:*

     ```
     #fitting separate Weibull distributions for each loc.id (may want to include year.id in 
     #the split)
     library(fitdistrplus)
     fit.weibull <- function(loc) {
       y <- summary(fitdist(loc,'weibull'))[[1]]
       return(y)
     }
     params <- lapply(time.sample, fit.weibull) #apply to each element in time sample
     ```
   - Finally, consider the inclusion of a location parameter, which shifts the graph of the pdf in a negative or positive direction along the x-axis; this should be appropriate because in many locations, no area gets plotted until the $X=2^{nd}$ week.  The inclusion of a location parameter would likely improve the fit of your distributions.
2. Use the fitted cdf (with the parameters informed by the previous step) to predict the cumulative proportion of area planted on a certain day for a given location.

   - It is important to understand what you are doing when you want to rescale the random variable time $X$ to represent days rather than weeks, which simply involves dividing the data (a vector of time observations) by 7.  This can be seen in the equation for the Weibull pdf itself.

     *I've demonstrated it through a few lines of R:*

     ```
     #creating predictive model - on a daily rather than weekly domain
     predict1.cum.plant <- function(day, loc.id, params) {
       #'scaling' 7x the scale parameter
       pweibull(day, shape=params[[loc.id]][[1]], scale=params[[loc.id]][[2]]*7)  
     }

     predict2.cum.plant <- function(day, loc.id, params) {
       #'scaling' 1/7x the random variable time
       pweibull(day/7, shape=params[[loc.id]][[1]], scale=params[[loc.id]][[2]])  
     }

     #example - the models are equal, which is obvious from the cdf equation!
     predict1.cum.plant(35, 2, params)
     predict2.cum.plant(35, 2, params) 
     pweibull(5, shape=params[[2]][[1]], scale=params[[2]][[2]]) #by week
     ```

*Some supplemental code of mine can be found [here](https://github.com/rahil-p/stack-exchange/blob/master/weibull/weibull.R).*

*Very similar methods can be used to fit a Beta distribution.*

Comment: This is quite a detailed and knowledgeable post. I thank you a lot. Regads

Comment: I have a question:  this is cdf for weibull `1 - exp(-(x/scale.par)^shape.par)`. From the above analysis, I first get scale and shape parameter from weekly data. For a location, if I want to find the cumulative planted in week 2 starting from week 1, the equation becomes `1 - exp(-(1/scale.par)^shape.par)`. If I want to know, the cumulative percent planted on last day of week 2, starting 1st day of week 1, I do `1 - exp(-(14/scale.par)^shape.par)` where 14 is the total no. of days from day 1 week 1 till day 14 week 2. In the second case, does the scale parameters gets multiplied by 7?

Comment: Yes - multiplying the scale parameter by 7 is equivalent to dividing the day input by 7, thereby translating any day input into its equivalent week input (which is what the data is fitted on)

Comment: But this answer assumes that one has random samples from a Weibull distribution.  What you have here is a regression in which the shape is similar to a Weibull.  Am I misinterpreting the data and the objective?

Comment: @JimB you are correct. After talking to the authors of the paper, I realised that a weibull regression is what is needed.  They did a weibull regression to each of the location and got the shape and the scale parameters.

Comment: I have posted a new question here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/348396/how-to-fit-a-weibull-regression Hopefully now my question is clear. thank you for the discussion with you